# Using MCMC to sample from a posterior, are our posterior beliefs on parameters independent?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, posterior

I've been given a classification problem in which MCMC (slice-sampling) is used to sample from a hierarchical posterior. After getting $n$ samples, the Monte Carlo method can be used to give an estimate of parameters of the model.

My question is: Are our posterior beliefs about individual parameters independent? I would argue they are not, as each sample in slice-sampling is auto-correlated...

Comment: I've rolled your edit back, leaving it as only saying "I've been given a classification problem" made the question unanswerable. Since you had a question which had an answer please only change it to clarify your question, not to remove context necessary for the answer to apply.

Comment: This feels somewhat unclear - at first reading I thought "Are our posterior beliefs about individual parameters independent" asks whether, say, parameter $\mu$ and parameter $\sigma^2$ are a posteriori independent, however, the answer does not talk about this and it's unclear how the slice-sampler would be related. Is the question actually concerned with the approximation of the posterior of parameter $\mu$ and the approximation of the posterior of parameter $\sigma$ (data and thus the underlying true posterior distribution treated fixed)?

Answer (score 3):

The posterior beliefs about the parameters are represented by the posterior distribution $\pi(\theta|\mathfrak{D})$ if $\mathfrak{D}$ denotes the data. This is a distribution *conditional* or *dependent* on the data.

Since this distribution is too complex to envision as such, we use simulation techniques to understand it. For instance, MCMC simulation produces an outcome $(\theta^{(t)})_t$ that is approximately distributed from $\pi(\theta|\mathfrak{D})$ and with correlated entries. They are therefore *dependent*.

Hence the answer to your question is that the approximation technique creates dependence, but the posterior beliefs themselves are not associated with any sort of dependence, except on the data $\mathfrak{D}$. It is important to distinguish the inference part from the simulation part as they partake of fundamentally different concepts.